# How to Launch Asynchronous Background Process in JXA

Tags: javascript, macos, cocoa, automator, javascript-automation

I'm trying to get an HTTP server running from a JXA (JavaScript for Automation) Mac app. This part is easy as easy as:

```
app.doShellScript("python -m SimpleHTTPServer");
```

(More info here: https://github.com/JXA-Cookbook/JXA-Cookbook/wiki/Shell-and-CLI-Interactions)

The problem is, after you've done that, the application process halts because the shell script doesn't actually quit.

Well then ... we just need to make the server run as a background process right?. Unfortunately, *none of the things I've tried have transferred control back to the JXA app*.

Here's what I've tried:

1. `app.doShellScript("nohup python -m SimpleHTTPServer > /dev/null <&- >&- 2>&- & disown");`
2. `app.doShellScript("( python -m SimpleHTTPServer > /dev/null & )");`
3. `$.system("( python -m SimpleHTTPServer & )");`
4. Wrote a python script that would launch another process that runs the server and quits
5. Tried the same thing in Node.js
6. Tried a shell script that would launch the server and end with `exit 0`
7. Tried firing up a `cron` job that would launch the shell script immediately that would launch the server, but it appears there are sandboxing issues with CRON.
8. Various hacks with `$.NSTask`

It seems that the eventual solution will involve the background process being launch in a way that is *completely 100% zero-knowledge detached* from the JXA application.

Comment: `app` in this case is referring to a terminal right? So a solution may be to create two `app` objects... one for running the http server and another one to do whatever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after a system reboot, it turns out this works:

```
$.system("nohup python -m SimpleHTTPServer > /dev/null &");
console.log("Non-blocking!");
```

(Thank you StackOverflow for being my [rubber duck](https://rubberduckdebugging.com/).)